# Django form in templatags

Tags: python, html, django

I need to place my form diffrent pages.

How can I render form in my html?
templatetags.py(https://i.stack.imgur.com/um4GL.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 1):

You can render your form in your template with a normal template tag with its variable name:

```
{{ form }}
```

This will use the `FORM_RENDERER` defined in your settings (defaults to `django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'`).
You have even more render options described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options).

Read more in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates) about working with forms.